# Figuring out why django can't find scripts, stylesheets, and plug-ins for my template right now

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I inherited a project and I've been trying to get the file structure correct on my local machine but I haven't been able to figure it out.

My django project is called gtr_site. On the home page html file, which is located in a .../templates/gtr_site/home.html path, I am trying to load scripts and stylesheets from a folder called "vendor" and its contents. The file within home.html to attempt to link some bootstrap code is as follows: `<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

When I first came across this, I made the assumption that i could be okay by creating a folder called "vendor" in same directory as home.html (in templates/gtr_site/), then creating the following directories and inserting the bootstrap file into the final directory. That hasn't worked.

I get the following error messages for various files in the vendor folder:

`[19/Aug/2017 15:53:35] "GET /gtr/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1798`
`Not Found: /gtr/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css/`

[image: A picture of the vendor directory, leading up to the bootstrap.min file. Still doesn't work]

So... my original approach of just creating a folder called "vendor" and going from there didn't work.

Because of that, I'm left with the question of "where is this html file supposed to be searching for a folder called vendor? Is it able to find one?" I don't know necessarily how to answer these questions.

I've been copying and pasting the "vendor" folder in various locations but haven't been successful.

The last thing is that I know settings.py is the place to go to have better control over where exactly template directories and static directories are supposed to be. But i also am not sure what needs to be changed or how at the moment. I'm also intimidated by the fact that this "worked" on another person's machine at some point, and I'm not sure what difference has been created by my machine and what adjustments I have to make.

Some potentially relevant lines from settings.py:

```
   BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'gtr_site.apps.GtrSiteConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  ]


      TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

     STATIC_URL = '/static/'

     STATIC_ROOT = '/srv/global-terrorism-research/gtr_site/static'
```

Are there at the very least any tips that someone can offer me so that I can fix this? No matter where I've tried to put the "vendor" folder so far I haven't found success. If I need to break up the vendor folder into something else... is there documentation that could help explain what I need to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link inside your template should include the keyword `static` to match the  app subfolder inside the folder static (the static folder should be in the app main folder directly, not inside the templates)

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
<link href={% static "gtr_site/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" %} rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, the url patterns should include this line :

```
urlpatterns = [
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thank you. Also kind of basic but don't forget to include {% load staticfiles %} in your code otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that before